# Distance between a point and a set 4

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, $k\geq2$, and $B_{n}$ the set of the points having a distance equal to $1/n$ form $A$, and $n=1,2,...$. Can we say that for all $a$ in the boundary of $ A$ there is a sequence $(b_{n})$ in $B_{n}$ that converges to $a$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we cannot. If $A$ is a dense subset then $B_n$ is empty for all $n$. If furthermore the interior of $A$ is empty, then the boundary of $A$ is the entire space, and so for none of its points will there exist a sequence of points $b_n$ from $B_n$ that converges to it. An example of such an $A$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^k$ whose coordinates are rational.